# Skip element with continue is not working properly in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, debugging, if-statement, foreach

I a have problem with skipping element in `foreach()`. It should skip all `$priznaky[$key]` when RESERVED but it will skip only the first RESERVED and it will display all other RESERVED:

```
foreach ($priznaky as $key=>$value) {     
  if($priznaky[$key] == "RESERVED"){
    continue;
  }
  else{
    $data1 .= "
      <tr>
        <td>" .$priznaky[$key]. "</td>
        <td>" .$zapsan. "</td> 
      </tr>
    ";    
  }
}
```

Result of `print_r($priznaky);`:

```
(
    [0] => RESERVED
    [1] => 
příznak existence subjektu v Obchodním rejstříku
    [2] => 
příznak existence subjektu ve statistickém Registru ekonomických subjektů
    [3] => 
příznak existence subjektu v Registru živnostenského podnikání
    [4] => 
příznak existence subjektu v Registru zdravotnických zařízení
    [5] => 
příznak existence subjektu v Registru plátců daně z přidané hodnoty
    [6] => 
příznak existence subjektu v Registru plátců spotřební daně
    [7] => 
RESERVED
    [8] => 
příznak existence subjektu v registru Centrální evidence úpadců - konkurz
    [9] => 
příznak existence subjektu v registru Centrální evidence úpadců - vyrovnání
    [10] => 
příznak existence subjektu v registru Centrální evidence dotací z rozpočtu
    [11] => 
příznak existence subjektu v účelovém registru organizací systému ARIS
    [12] => 
RESERVED
    [13] => 
příznak existence subjektu v Registru církví a náboženských společností
    [14] => 
příznak existence subjektu v Seznamu politických stran a hnutí
    [15] => 
RESERVED
    [16] => 
RESERVED
    [17] => 
RESERVED
    [18] => 
RESERVED
    [19] => 
příznak existence subjektu v seznamu Občanských sdružení a spolků
    [20] => 
příznak existence subjektu v Zemědělském registru
    [21] => 
příznak existence subjektu v Insolvenčním rejstříku
    [22] => 
příznak existence subjektu v Rejstříku škol a školských zařízení
    [23] => 
RESERVED
    [24] => 
RESERVED
    [25] => 
RESERVED
    [26] => 
RESERVED
    [27] => 
RESERVED
    [28] => 
RESERVED
    [29] => 
RESERVED
    [30] => 
)
```

Comment: Is the `continue` even necessary here? Why not just `if($priznaky[$key] != "RESERVED") {...`?

Comment: Why not just go with something like `if($priznaky[$key] != "RESERVED"){ ... }` ? As mentioned, why are you referring to the actual array again instead of using the `$value` variable? `$value` is the equivalent to `$priznaky[$key]` unless you're meaning to change the actual array itself, which does not appear to be the case.

Comment: Instead of doing `$priznaky[$key]`, just do `$value`. It makes your code more readable and it's easier to write. Also, please post the output of `print_r($priznaky);`

Comment: Can you `var_dump($priznaky);` please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to be newlines in the data.  From your `print_r()`:

```
    [0] => RESERVED
    [15] => 
RESERVED
    [16] => 
RESERVED
    [17] => 
RESERVED
    [18] =>
RESERVED
```

See a difference there?  So `trim()` it. Also, it's easier to just use `$value` and no need for `continue` if you flip your logic:

```
foreach($priznaky as $value) {
    if(trim($value) !== "RESERVED"){
        $data1 .= "
          <tr>
            <td>" .$value. "</td>
            <td>" .$zapsan. "</td> 
          </tr>
        ";    
    }
}
```

You could also check for `strpos($value, 'RESERVED') !== false` if the newline is not the only issue.

Comment: Thanks, but i dont know why newline appeard there beacause in file from which it is loading this text it have only 30 lines. Maybe something from this:
`$priznaky_txt = fopen("priznaky.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
 $priznaky = explode("|",fread($priznaky_txt,filesize("priznaky.txt")));`

Comment: And file priznaky.txt looks like that:
`RESERVED|
příznak existence subjektu v Obchodním rejstříku|
příznak existence subjektu ve statistickém Registru ekonomických subjektů|
příznak existence subjektu v Registru živnostenského podnikání|
příznak existence subjektu v Registru zdravotnických zařízení|
příznak existence subjektu v Registru plátců daně z přidané hodnoty|
příznak existence subjektu v Registru plátců spotřební daně|
RESERVED|
příznak existence subjektu v registru Centrální evidence úpadců - konkurz|
RESERVED|
RESERVED|`

Comment: I would use `file()` with `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` and `str_getcsv()` with `|` delimiter maybe.